# Allpass filter feedforward/feedback design and code

Tags: filters, audio, delay, allpass, feedback

I want to design/implement a simple feedforward/feedback all-pass filter, and I am having some troubles and questions with it.

From Shroeder design (based on J. Smith article [here](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/realsimple/Delay/Allpass_Filters_I.html)):
[image: Feedback/feedforward all-pass]

I came up with the following pseudocode (for first-order all-pass filter, meaning the delay was set to 1 sample, and `b0 = aM`):

```
float allPassGain = aM, value from [0.0, 1.0);

float allPassFeedback = 0.0;
float allPassDelayedSample = 0.0;

float processAllPass(float x)
{
    float delayInput = x + allPassFeedback;
    float feedForward = delayInput * allPassGain;

    float delayOutput = allPassDelayedSample;
    allPassDelayedSample = delayInput;

    allPassFeedback = delayOutput * -allPassGain;

    return delayOutput + feedForward;
}
```

Here `x` is an input sample, to process some signal with this all-pass I am going through the signal feeding it sample-by-sample into `processAllPass`, and store the outputs in the parallel output signal.

But unfortunately it seems like this approach doesn't work. For example, if I create a simple [Phaser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phaser_(effect)) with a set of successful all-pass filters designed like that, I don't get the desired effect, instead the signal becomes unstable and shoots through the roof.

Does the pseudo-code have issues? I am setting `aM` to an arbitrary value and the delay line length is strictly 1.

---

Matt L.'s answer helped me to fix the code, and here is the fixed pseudo-code if that would be interesting (please also note that for the Phaser effect I find it better to switch coefficients' signs, it is slightly different version of the all-pass filter, presented in e.g. `"Reducing Artificial Reverberation Algorithm Requirements using FDN" by Jasmin Frenette`):

```
float allPassGain = aM, value from [0.0, 1.0);

float allPassDelayedSample = 0.0;

float processAllPass(float x)
{
    float delayOutput = allPassDelayedSample;
    float feedBack = delayOutput * allPassGain;

    float delayInput = inSamp + feedBack;
    float feedForward = delayInput * -allPassGain;
    allPassDelayedSample = delayInput;

    return delayOutput + feedForward;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all make sure that the magnitude of $a_M$ is strictly less than $1$; this is necessary for the filter's stability. Second, you use several unnecessary variables. This is no serious problem, but it makes it harder to see what's going on. For $M=1$ a simple pseudo-code would be

```
v = x - aM * v_old;
y = v * b + v_old;
v_old = v;
```

The important thing is that the state variable `v_old` must be remembered between function calls. Are you sure that your variables `allPassFeedback` and `allPassDelayedSample` are not reset to $0$ every time you call the function?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! `aM` is less than 1, yes, so better would be `value from [0.0, 1.0)`. As for the unnecessary variables -- I did that for clearer (diagram-pseudo code) transition, but I will check if my code could be simplified to yours. The variables you're asking about are not reset to 0 everytime, I checked that

Comment: Hm, yours pseudocode is a bit different than mine it seems, in mine I have additional delay, so the feedback seems to act like additional delay line (I am calculating/storing the feedback after I get the delay line outputs, but use the feedback earlier), probably that's the difference that hurts, I will check!

Comment: Yes! This was the difference ruining everything, so after I quickly re-done the feedback line to contain immediate outputs from the delay line (/w gain), the filter worked, thanks for your answer! Can't upvote it since I have no reputation though :(